# Do I need to get a visa for Turkey?

Tags: visas, turkey, german-citizens

I'm going to travel to Iran from Germany. Since I've booked connected flights (Germany- Turkey, Turkey- Iran), do I need a visa for Turkey as well as Iran?

This is my flights schedule:

> - Basel-Mulhouse-Freiburg (check-in Swiss sector) to Istanbul - Sabiha
>     Gökçen
>
>   Dep 19 May 2012 22:30
>
>   Arr 20 May 2012 02:25
> - Istanbul - S.Gokcen(SAW)Tehran - IKA(IKA)
>
>   Departure: IST (SAW) 20.05.2012  23:05
>
>   Arrival:THR (IKA) 21.05.2012 03:25

So if I need a visa planning to leave the airport for a few hours to Istanbul until the next flight, I would stay at the airport.

Note: I have German nationality.

Comment: You should add your citizenship.

Comment: Citizenship doesn't really matter - this is a generic question. Personally, I'd like to see it reworded to "Do I need a visa for a country if I'm just changing planes?"

Comment: It matters. When it comes to Visa and entry regulations, citizenship is one of the most important variables.

Comment: Are you just changing planes at the airport in Turkey or are you spending time there?

Comment: @hippietrail: Added.

Comment: Thanks @Gigili. If you weren't intending to leave the aiport I would've also added the [tag:transit] tag.

Comment: @AffableGeek And the generic answer is: It depends (in particular on the country, the airport, the flights, the duration of the transit and, you guessed it, your citizenship).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a German citizen you can spend up to 90 days within a period of 180 days in [Turkey](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Laenderinformationen/00-SiHi/TuerkeiSicherheit.html?nn=338384#doc336356bodyText4), without visa. A passport or ID card (Personalausweis) is enough.

For [Iran](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Laenderinformationen/00-SiHi/IranSicherheit.html?nn=337790#doc337572bodyText4), you need a passport without stamp from Israel, and a visa.

Comment: Doesn't matter if I'd leave the airport to Istanbul for a few hours?

Comment: It does not matter, as long as you stay below the threshold mentioned above (90 days within 180).

Answer (score 2):

Istanbul airport provides [free tours](http://www.istanbulinhours.com/) for those with 6-24 hour layovers, which appears to include you. The info page for the tour points to a [Turkish government page](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa) which says that Germans do not need a visa for stays of up to 90 days.

I had two 4-hour layovers in that airport and while the lounge was nice, I kind of had my nose pressed up against the glass wishing I could go out and see the city. Take the free tour, it should be fun!