# As European citizen (Italian), do I need a passport or ID card to get to Istanbul?

Tags: visas, turkey, italian-citizens

I'm a European Citizen (Italian), I'm planning to go to Istanbul in a very short time.
I'm not sure I've time to make my passport, so I would like to know if I can get to Turkey with just my ID Card, valid for expatriation.

There is [this answer which states that it is possible](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/6529/4629). However it is a bit outdated, things my have changed meanwhile. Also it doesn't report to any referenced official website.

Can you help me?

Comment: You national ID card is not particularly “valid for expatriation”. It is recognized within the EU, for any purpose, but usually not in other countries (although there are some exceptions, including Turkey).

Comment: as an Italian citizen you should always consult the official site of "Ministro degli esteri", [the page about Turkey states you can enter with your carta d'identià only](http://www.viaggiaresicuri.it/?turchia)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can go to Istanbul with your ID card.

Generally speaking, Kris is right, you do need a valid passport, even for countries for which you don't need a visa.

But in this case, you can in fact enter Turkey with your national ID (see [this official page from the Turkish ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/countries-whose-citizens-are-allowed-to-enter-turkey-with-their-national-id_s.en.mfa) and [the relevant page from the Italian ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.viaggiaresicuri.it/?turchia) mentioned by Geeo). This possibility is only offered to citizens from a few countries (not the whole EU) but it's the case for Italian citizens.

Citizens from an even smaller list of countries can also enter with an *expired* passport but that's not the case for Italy.